# Add drawables to Edit Text

Tags: android, image, android-edittext

What i want to accomplish is adding some images in a Edit Text . Something like Free Note . So this is what i accomplished until now:
This is how i add images.

```
    EditTextCustom text = (EditTextCustom)findViewById(R.id.EditText);
    Drawable img = this.getResources().getDrawable( R.drawable.delete);
    img.setBounds( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, img, null);
```

And my EditTextCustom class looks like this:

```
public class EditTextCustom extends EditText {

    private Drawable dRight;

    public EditTextCustom(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean onCheckIsTextEditor() {
        return false;
    } 

    @Override
    public void setCompoundDrawables(Drawable left, Drawable top,
        Drawable right, Drawable bottom)
    {
        if(right !=null)
        {
            dRight = right;
        }
        super.setCompoundDrawables(left, top, right, bottom);
    }

}
```

The problem is that the Edit Text is has more than one line and i don't know how i could accomplish adding the images on the top left corner.